# "The data has been changed" error when editing underlying record in Access VBA

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a form in Access where I have 2 unbound multi-select listboxes, with some code to move items between them.

Each of the fields in the table which are shown in the listboxes are boolean values - if the value is true then the name of that field shows up in `lstSelected`, and if false shows up in `lstUnselected`.

The listboxes have a RowSourceType of Value List, and the value list is generated programatically by looking at the underlying record and constructing a string with the field names where the boolean values are true for `lstSelected` and False for `lstUnselected`.

On the form I have two buttons, `cmdMoveToSelected` and `cmdMoveToUnselected`. When I click on `cmdMoveToSelected` it changes the boolean value of the underlying field for any selected items in the `lstUnselected` listbox from false to true by executing an SQL string, then rebuilds the value lists for both of the listboxes.

I have all of this working just fine. If I do a `me.lstUnwanted.requery` and a `me.lstwanted.requery` then everything moves and shows up correctly, and the underlying fields are edited correctly, BUT when I click on anything else on the form I get the error:

> The data has been changed.
>
> Another  user edited this record and saved the changes before you attempted to save your changes.
>
> Re-edit the record.

Now I've found a way around this (`jobDetailsID` is the primary key of the record being dealt with):

```
    Dim intCurID as Integer

    intCurID = Me.JobDetailsID

    Me.Form.Requery

    Me.Recordset.FindFirst "JobDetailsID = " & curID
```

This requeries the form and then moves back to the current record, and this gets rid of the error, however it causes there to be a delay and the form to flicker while it opens back at the first record, changes back to the correct record and repopulates the list boxes.

Is there a way to do away with this error, or get it to trigger programmatically so I can catch it by turning the warnings off via vba?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it helps not to bind the form to the table being altered by cmdMoveToSelected, but to a query that doesn't contain all the boolean fields. If cmdMoveToSelected alters one or more boolean fields, the record is changed, but the query result isn't. Not sure if it's sound though.

It also sounds a bit like a design problem rather than a form problem, storing options in boolean fields instead of into a related table.

Comment: Interesting suggestion but I don't really think it would help. If the form is running VBA code that is altering the current record directly (i.e., not through the form's Record Source) then there will probably still be a locking conflict at the table level regardless of whether the form is bound directly to the table or is bound to an updatable query based on that table.

Comment: The structure does make sense. I thought about having them in a separate table or something but let me explain. We're storing info about job in a joinery workshop. We make a number of standard products each of which have options. Each boolean field denotes whether a certain thing is included in the job - so one might be "Roof glass included" and another "Special glazing bead required". All together I have around 70 fields (and none are repeating sets), but they do need to have the same info on every single job. I'm open to suggestions of better structures though.

Comment: If you store the options in the Jobs table, all options have a default value (true or false). If the options are about say SpokenLanguage in a Persons table, having that default value is not wanted since you assume upon creating Persons that they do or do not speak that language. In your case it could be more applicable, but only if you store identical Job types. When storing different Job types, different options apply, and all options for a certain Job type would have to get fields in the table.

Comment: I can imagine an approach like:
Jobtypes: f.i. chair or plank (your standard products) (id, description)
Jobtypeoptions: default options for a certain jobtype (id, job_type, option, default)
Jobs: Working order, inserted when a product is ordered (id, job_type)
Joboptions: the default options for Jobs.Jobtype are inserted when a product is ordered (id, job, option, value)
The first two tables contain base info about what you create and how you can do that, the last two tables are 'working' tables used for production.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution would be to *not* directly update the current record in the table while the Form is dirty. Instead, update the values of the fields within the form itself (`Me!FieldName`) as the items are moved from one List Box to the other, and let the form write those values back to the table as usual.

Comment: The listboxes are unbound, it's only the ID field that's shown on the form which is bound to the underlying table, so `me!fieldname` to change the value gives me "You can't assign a value to this object".

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed it, though the fix doesn't make a great deal of sense to me.

I added in a `Me.Refresh` to the button click code, after I had requeried the two listboxes and it appears to have stopped the message from coming up. *However* this only works when I have the `JobDetailsID` textbox visible on the form (though I expect this is arbitrary and any field-linked textbox would work).

Can anybody explain to me why this works? I'd like to understand fully when to use requery, refresh etc

Answer (score 0):

I've had this sort of thing happen when I've left the form RowSource query hanging in place after converting the controls to unbound textboxes, etc. The general Form rowsource query (to bring in all fields I might possibly end up using) provides me with a query-list identical to the table fieldnames, making it simple to select them for control-names as needed. Works fine, but you have to remove the form rowsource query after all the names are matched-up. (After which DLookup and BeforeUpdate works for getting and storing values and changes.)